# Problemas con los operadores de comparación

Tags: javascript, operador

quería hacer un ejercicio en el cual tenia que agrupar precios según su coste pero no ejecuta la linea 29, 33 y 39 y  y no esta mal declarada por que intercambie de lugar con otros if's e igual no funciona, tampoco esta mal escrita y la siguiente linea se ejecuta bien, la verdad que no se que mas hacer, es como si ignorase las líneas antes mencionadas

```js
let helado1 = prompt("Precio de helado 1");
let helado2 = prompt("Precio de helado 2");
let helado3 = prompt("Precio de helado 3");

let caro = null;
let doscaros = null;
let medio = null;
let barato = null;
let dosbaratos = null;
let iguales = null;
let iguales2 = null;
let iguales3 = null;


if(helado1 > helado2){
   if(helado2 > helado3){caro = helado1, medio = helado2, barato = helado3;}
   else if(helado1 == helado3){caro = helado3, doscaros = helado1,barato = helado2;}
   else{caro = helado1, barato = helado3, dosbaratos = helado2;}
}
else if(helado2 > helado1){
    if(helado1 > helado3){caro = helado2, medio = helado1, barato = helado3;}
    else if(helado2 == helado3){caro = helado3, doscaros = helado2, barato = helado1;}
    else{caro = helado2, barato= helado3, dosbaratos = helado1;}
}



else if(helado3 > helado1){
    if(helado1 > helado2){caro = helado3, medio = helado1, barato = helado2;}
     else{barato = helado1, dosbaratos = helado2, caro = helado3;}
}
else if(helado1 > helado3){
     if(helado3 > helado2){caro = helado1, medio = helado3, barato = helado2;}
     else{caro = helado2, doscaros = helado1, barato = helado3;}
}



else if(helado2 > helado3 && helado3 > helado1){caro = helado2, medio = helado3, barato= helado1;}
else{iguales = helado1, iguales2 = helado2, iguales3 = helados3};

alert("el mas caro es : "+ caro);
alert("doscaros : " + doscaros);
alert("medio : " + medio);
alert("dosbaratos : " + dosbaratos);
alert("barato : " + barato);
alert("todos iguales : " + iguales);
alert("ya ta");
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que la función `prompt` retorna un `string`, lo cual hace que fallen tus comparaciones. Tal cual como lo tienes ahora una comparación de tipo:

```js
'223' > '92' // ---> False
```

Ya que los operadores de comparación en strings funcionan diferente.

Una solución sencilla que puedes aplicar es convertir o castear el tipo `string` a `number`, lo puedes hacer así:

```js
let helado1 = parseInt(prompt("Precio de helado 1"));
```

O también así:

```js
let helado1 = +prompt("Precio de helado 1");
```

Cualquier otro problema que puedas tener será meramente de lógica.

Comment: no te olvides del segundo parámetro de parseInt, para que no se quejen los linters